# Is there a special contract format that must be followed when hiring an unpaid intern in the US?

Tags: hiring-process, internship, united-states

I am interested in hiring an unpaid intern in the United States. I have reviewed [the outline from the Dept. of Labor](http://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs71.pdf), and I meet the criteria.

I have an LLC, and I want to bring in a college student. We'll work on a portfolio site for the intern, so I won't be gaining any advantage of any kind. I simply want to help college students who need course credit.

Do I have to file special forms, or can I simply draw up a contract with them stating what we'll be doing and explicitly saying they won't be getting paid and they won't get a job?